# Anonymous video uploading on an internet host

Tags: anonymity, tor, file-upload

How much video uploading could be trackable for some person who uses the Tor Browser for uploading video on YouTube or other video hosting services with low authorization and sign-up processing, like Vimeo?

And which group (hackers or …) have the ability to track this target?

Answer (score 0):

depends on platform, some websites processed metadata (to track activities). basically its one of the way to trace video. there lot of articles and white papers on TOR tracing. :)

yes there are people/groups who can trace this activity, they are specialized in Digital Forensics and Threat Intelligence.

Comment: :), here is something . if any one wants to upload this kind of videos, they can alter their metadata which can mislead the agencies/people. tools/github scripts available. use this information for education purpose.